# proper size for Javascript

Tags: javascript, minify, uglifyjs

I am working on minify and uglify my javascript files.
I am wondering how big the proper size is.
If I combine all js files into a file (with minifying and uglifying), it is bigger than 1mb.
I guess, it's better to chop them into 2-3 files (200kb-300kb for each) instead of one big file (1mb).

Can anyone give a suggestion?
like 100kb ~ 300kb or 1mb ~ 2mb

============ additional comment ============

I am using Django(Backend) & angularJS (Frontend).
as far as I know, all js files for angularJS should be sent to user when index(root html file) html file sent.
That's why the Concatenated js files (including external js file such as jquery, bootstrap, angular, media player and etc...) is more than 1mb.

Comment: For HTTP/1.1, the rule is less resources is usually better. For HTTP/2, more resources doesn't necessarily cause more requests, so smaller files can result in better caching.

Comment: Less is better, but I will mention that the entire JS portion of the codebase of my game is 450kb *before* minification. If you're getting 1Mb *after* minification then there's something very wrong.

Comment: What is the use case? website? game? :)

Comment: Who said it was a game ? =P

Comment: The maths here `2-3 files (200kb-300kb for each) instead of one big file (1mb).` does not add up

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: What went wrong is over-reliance on libraries. Unfortunately for professionally written code it's sometimes unavoidable because your boss won't accept you taking a whole year to write a super-optimized feature from scratch. So you use jQuery etc. The webapp I currently maintain has 4MB of js code. It uses jQuery, prototype, ckeditor, a homegrown js DOM library, React.js and I believe there's underscore in there as well. My own webapp has around 600k

Comment: @slebetman: you told what I really want to tell. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no one proper size. The less bytes the better, but it depends on your code base it order to determine how small you can realistically get. The bigger the file, the greater network latency retrieving the files (so, this will impact the user more negatively). So if you had to come up with a general "rule", the smaller the better.

Answer (score 1):

There is no correct answer for your question. Some recommendations, since you have a large app to load:

- split up your app in modules and load the modules as you need, this way you can start the app quickly and the user will require the other modules as it uses the app.
- show some visual feedback while you load the needed files, most common example is a spinning wheel, but it could be a pong game. The key is to entertain the user since no one wants to wait
- use server and client cache, don't forget to add cache headers that leverage client cache
- split up your build source code from vendor, vendor tends to change less, so you can take more advantage of cache

Comment: First of all, Thanks for your kind reply. 1) split up your app in modules and load the modules as you need : yes, I actually did, but as I mentioned above, all js files should be sent to user at first since I use AngularJS. 2) show some visual feedback while you load the needed files. yes, it has been added. 3) use server and client cache. I haven't think about it. I'll look over it 4) split up your build source code from vendor. I'll think about it Thanks!